# Mouse Sensitivity

Tags: mouse

I don't understand.

Can I just change the mouse sensitivity ( speed, NOT acceleration ) in Ubuntu?

I've tried xinput set-prop for my mouse ( which by the way does not even have the `Device Accel Constant Deceleration` which is considered to be mouse sensitivity ) until I plug it out and plug it back in. I've tried `xset m 1 5` or really anything similar to that. The "Mouse Speed" slider in Mouse settings is literally not changing anything. I literally can not find ANYTHING that will change my mouse movement in ANY way.

I'm using an A4Tech Bloody V3 in Ubuntu 15.04.

Thank you.